# Solving a many-to-many relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

**Background**: A company has over 5000 employees and has buildings placed in different cities. 1 Employee can be working in 2 or more of these buildings depending on the day/project. The company does not keep a track of on which day someone is in what building. They only have one sheet with all Employee data and location data. This location also includes a start date of on which date the employee started going to that location. It looks like the following:

```
EmployeeID | FirstName | LastName | email | BuildingID | Buildinglocation | startdate
1          | John      | Gates    | JG@.. | 2          | New York         | 01-01-2015
1          | John      | Gates    | JG@.. | 1          | Paris            | 01-05-2015
2          | Bill      | Jobs     | BJ@.. | 2          | New York         | 01-01-2016
3          | Carl      | Davis    | CD@.. | 3          | London           | 01-11-2015
```

I need to turn this into multiple tables to create a datawarehouse. What I was thinking about was a table for `employee` and one for `location`. This however, would be a `many to many relation`, so I wanted to add a `bridge table`.

The question is: Where do I save the `startdate`? Should I add it in the Bridge table? How do I populate it with the `startdate` in that case? Or should I just leave it in the `location table`, making the relation between `employee` and `location` a 1-n relation?

Comment: I would put in in the bridge table because in the location table each location will exist only once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I would do:

I would put the `startdate` in your Bridge table as the `employee` and `location` would be made before they are joined together which then the `startdate` is populated. The `location` will only exist once, so by creating a separate table for it, you are doing less work and saving memory. Adding a constraint to startdate in your bridge table so that when a new row is added, it must have a date /auto populate will ensure that you will have the best data possible *If that makes sense*

Answer (score 2):

Your tables would look something like this :

employees

```
EmployeeID | FirstName | LastName | email   
1          | John      | Gates    | JG@..  
2          | Bill      | Jobs     | BJ@..  
3          | Carl      | Davis    | CD@..
```

buildings

```
BuildingID | Buildinglocation  
1          | Paris  
2          | New York  
3          | London
```

bridge table

```
EmployeeID | BuildingID | startdate  
1          | 2          | 01-01-2015  
1          | 1          | 01-05-2015  
2          | 2          | 01-01-2016  
3          | 3          | 01-11-2015
```